# Having to hit enter with nohup

Tags: linux

I have a shell command like this

```
sudo nohup coffee -c -w *.coffee &
disown $!
wait
```

but when I run the shell scrit it says `nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'` and makes me hit enter.
How do I get around having to hit enter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand, you don't have to. The message is output to the console, but not added to your *input* buffer. Therefore you can just continue typing your commands in as if there were no message from `nohup`, the message will not interfere with your input.

Well, having to type not from the exact prompt position may be aesthetically not so pleasing.

Answer (score 14):

8 year old thread, but I found that none of these answers really solve the issue in the question.

The message `nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'` is piped through stderr (AFAIK), so in order to silence that message, all you have to do is to redirect stderr to `/dev/null`, like so:

```
nohup mycommand 2> /dev/null
```

However, if you additionally want to run this process in the background with `&`, you will find that (for bash at least), there will be a single line output of the job number and PID (e.g. `[1] 27184`). To avoid this, run the entire command in a subshell, like so:

```
(nohup my command 2> /dev/null &)
```

But if you're using this in a script, the former solution is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You could also redirect the log manually: 
`sudo nohup coffee -c -w *.coffee > /tmp/coffee.log &`

That way the message won't show up at all.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Linux 20.04: None of the answers above solved the problem for me: script blocks in any case, waiting for input

*My Solution*

```
[sudo] nohup `command` > nohub.log < enter.txt  &
```

where `enter.txt` is a text file containing a single line separator.